# Unable to save plots from a Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I couldn't find any light on this topic.

After a clean restart in a new laptop I'm unable to download plots from a Jupyter notebook from Visual Studio Code.

According to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) and my past experiences with vscode this is as simple as click on the save icon of the output of the cell o double click on the plot and save from the emerging tab that opens. But, as you can see, I've lost that icon and double click does nothing [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gZsy.jpg)

I'd love to get back this feature.

Thx in advance!

My settings.json file has this lines:

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "Gruvbox Material Dark",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/anaconda3/envs/bin/python",
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
"notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
    "default": "right",
    "jupyter-notebook": "right"
},    

"editor.rulers": [
    {
      "column": 80,
      "color": "#928E7C20"
    },
    120
],

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sideBar.background": "#242424",
    "list.hoverBackground": "#292828",
    "notebook.cellEditorBackground": "#3D3F41",
    "notebook.outputContainerBackgroundColor": "#282828",
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but it was suddenly resolved.

I think it is because the renderer of plots is builtin one instead of `Jupyter Notebook Renderer`.

I'm not sure if the following procedure is correct, because I couldn't restore the condition before it was fixed.

1. Turn ON `jupyter.generateSVGPlots`.
2. Restart notebook.
3. Plot something and you may see an icon like `</>` on the left of the image.
4. Click on icon `</>` to switch Renderer to `Jupyter Notebook Renderer (image/png)`.
5. Turn OFF `jupyter.generateSVGPlots`.

it's been a long time, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thx! I moved to PyCharm but I recently need to move back to a given environment and selecting the Jupyter Notebook Renderer solved the issue.